# How to deal with a loop Service?

Tags: android, service

My Android application is activating a `service` that call an `'Activity`.
On mainActivity:

```
 startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(),MyService.class));
```

And then on service:

```
     public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flage,int startId){

//  Toast.makeText(this, "Yes please", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Intent mIntent=new Intent(MyService.this,trackingActivity.class);
    mIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(mIntent);

    return START_STICKY; }
```

At the end of trackingActivity this line is written (Again):

```
startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(),MyService.class));
```

That's creates a lot of `Services`. Is there a better way to create a background service that repeats itself always without creating each time a new `Service` ?

I tried to do a while loop inside the `Activity` :

```
      while(true){
                  Actions on activity
                  }
```

But with no success.

Comment: As per my answer, this does not create many services. So you do not need a better way - you are already not creating a new Service each time. Please explain the problem further if this is not the point.

Comment: now i understand,thanks Richard i will take both of this answers and combine them, i need a bind service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`Context.startService(Intent)` does not create a new `Service` for each call.**

If there is already a matching service running, it passes the intent to that running service, but does not create a new one each time.

---

See the Android Developer Docs for [Context.startService(Intent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService(android.content.Intent)):

> If this service is not already running, it will be instantiated and
> started (creating a process for it if needed); if it is running then
> it remains running.
>
> Every call to this method will result in a corresponding call to the target service's onStartCommand(Intent, int, int) method, with the intent given here.

---

There is similar information in the Android Developer Docs about [Starting a Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#StartingAService):

> [When starting a service using an intent] the startService() method returns immediately and the Android system
> calls the service's onStartCommand() method. If the service is not
> already running, the system first calls onCreate(), then calls
> onStartCommand().
>
> ...
>
> Multiple requests to start the service result in multiple
> corresponding calls to the service's onStartCommand(). However, only
> one request to stop the service (with stopSelf() or stopService()) is
> required to stop it.

Comment: `onStartCommand()` is called every time a client starts the service using `startService(Intent intent)` - so this is probably the reason why the OP thinks many services are started. In fact there might even be a loop, in case the activity starts the service again.

Comment: @Trinimon that is correct. The method is called each time, however the system does not create many services - this is what I am pointing out in my answer above.

Comment: i though this was creating a new service because at the activity an XML file is attached so each time i use the service i see a popup screen with the result, lets say i run the service 3 times (when i enter valuse through usb the service is activated), as i push the back touch button on my s3 after all three times i see all the 3 screens, and at the 4th time i see my main activity.